# Is it possible to represent "A implies B" , " A iff B" , " A Xor B " using a switching circuit diagram?

Tags: propositional-calculus

One commonly sees conjonction represented by 2 swiches on the same line ( " en série" as one says in French) and inclusive disjunction by 2 switches in parallel. But I've never seen the circuit that would represent implication, bi-implication or exclusive disjunction.   Is it possible? ( Any reference for this? )

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMPLY_gate

Comment: See also [Logic gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_gate).